# IN and OUT instructions in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, ioports

In 8086 the `in` and `out` instructions use a PIC port address as stored in AL or AX registers which in further is used with `out` instruction.
What happens if we don't give any port number in `in` instruction?
Does the `out` instruction still work?
If so, then how and what PIC port will be selected?

Comment: You'll find that there are no `in` or `out` instructions that do not have a port number attached to them.  The port number is either taken from an 8-bit immediate or from the contents of the `dx` register.

Comment: @fuz so does this mean if i dont put any pic port myself whatever hex value is in dx it will be considered as port?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The manual documents them pretty clearly: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in / https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/out

Comment: In most assemblers, you can't just omit the port number. You have to explicitly put a port number or put `dx` as the port operand.

Comment: @hadikhan: What assembler are you using?  What syntax are you using where you can omit a port number and it still assembles?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the port address is stored in `dx`, not `ax`. The data you want to write goes in `ax` or `al`.

`in` and `out` work differently than most other operations in that

```
out dx,al
in al,dx
```

are perfectly valid even though the register sizes don't match. This is similar to how you're allowed to do `mov al, byte ptr [bx]`, as your operand is using a register as a means of accessing memory, rather than storing it directly into a register itself.

I've never used an assembler that didn't have you specify a port, but since you either have to use a constant value or `DX`, it wouldn't be too much of a stretch to imagine there's an assembler out there that uses `DX` if only one operand is provided (kind of like how some 6502 assemblers make you type `LSR A` to do a right bit-shift on the `A` register when others are fine with just `LSR`.)

Which port you select is up to you, you're going to need to read the documentation for your associated peripheral to figure out which port number is needed. Remember that if you have a port number that is greater than 255, you'll need to use `DX`. Otherwise, you can just have the port number as a constant.